# Photoshop saves animated gif frames individually

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animated-gif

I am trying to save an animated gif using

```
File > Export > Save for Web Legacy
```

It saves the frames individually instead of as a complete animated gif. I've been trying for hours using different file sizes, resolutions, frame rates but the issue persists. I remember it use to work well. It puzzles me that it is not working now. Are there any settings that I need to check?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate the problem. It seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Hi Thanks @BillyKerr! This is the first time I encountered this too. It has been working fine for me. I wonder if it is any settings that I have altered without knowing it.

Comment: It turns out that it is a bug or glitch. After updating the software, it works as per normal.